# Toolbar has too small height

Tags: android, android-toolbar

Why Toolbar has so small height on start? But if user scrolls down then it looks like on second screenshot.

[image: Screenshot on start]
[image: Screenshot of expanded Toolbar]

As you can see on screenshot it also has incorrect top padding.
It's my layout xml of `MainActivity`:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Paper.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.Paper.PopupOverlay">

                <include
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    layout="@layout/toolbar_spinner" />

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            style="@style/Theme.Paper.FloatingActionButton"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <fragment
        class="com.test.modal.NavigatorFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        tools:layout="@layout/navigator"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Who knows that I doing wrong? In `FrameLayout` I inflate `ViewPager` if it has value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

so i think the problem is in   android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"

change it to   android:layout_height="match_parent"

and than see what happend !

Comment: Yeah, it really works! But I cannot understand bug all same... Why did AppBarLayout ignore height attribute?

Comment: You saved my whole day!